# the Dequeue method's job when it's called

Tags: java, queue

If I call the method `dequeue()` by saying `myQueue.dequeue();` what will happen? 
With mentioning that this is how I initialized myQueue.

```
QueueInterface<String> myQueue = new LinkedQueue<String>();
```

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: what is LinkedQueue class? Java has no built in class with this name.

Comment: public T dequeue ()
    {
        T front = null;
        if (!isEmpty ())
        {
            front = firstNode.getData ();
            firstNode = firstNode.getNextNode ();
            if (firstNode == null)
                lastNode = null;
        } // end if
        return front;
    } // end dequeue

Comment: this is its implementation but i don't get what it's exactly doing!!

Comment: The question isn't clear without the full queue class implementation in the body of the question. I recommend adding it there. Anyway, according to the method impl you added in a comment, it looks like this method removes the head of the queue and returns the data in it, as expected by a method with such a name.